# How to slice a geometry?

Tags: opengl

Let's say I have this geometry: 
`glutSolidTeapot(1);`

I want to slice it in 8 cubes, for example across the 3 planes (xy), (yz), (xz), to make a 3D puzzle.

How can I clip a geometry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is 2 ways of doing this. I'm going to assume you want to slice your geometry into cubes, but other shapes can be done similarly.

#### 1. Slice your triangle mesh

Here you just loop through all your triangles and check in which cube the triangle belongs to. If the triangle intersects multiple cubes you need to split it in multiple triangles. You'll need to do some math for line-plane intersection to get the splits right, but its not very hard.

#### 2. Use opengl clip planes

You can also render your geometry multiple times, but clip only the part you want to be shown on screen. This can be done using glClipPlane (see http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClipPlane.xml). For each cube you'll need 6 clip planes. This method will be slower than the first as gpu needs to consider each triangle for every cube.